# When will season 3 of Heaven's Lost Property come out?

Tags: sora-no-otoshimono

I've been wondering if season 3 for heaven's lost property would come out or if it was already out. Could direct me to the place where I could find it? If it isn't out yet, would you happen to know if it will come out and when exactly might it come out? I am a U.S. Citizen but I am currently not in the mainland. I'm at Hawaii and hopefully me telling you that might help...

Answer (score 4):

The [official announcement](http://kadokawa-anime.jp/soraoto/2013/10/2014.html) for the second film stated:

> 『「第３期シリーズ」として発表しておりましたが、この度シリーズ作品ではなく...2014年に劇場公開することが大決定しました！！』
>
> "**Although we had previously said there would be a third series** [season], this time **instead** of a series...in 2014 it's been decided that there will be a theatrical release!"

A third season of the TV anime had been previously [promised](http://kadokawa-anime.jp/soraoto/2013/10/2014.html) in the March 2012 issue of 「月刊少年エース」 (*Gekkan Shounen Ace*) magazine, but the film announcement corrects that to state that **there will not be any further TV anime**. The second film is a replacement for season three.

Comment: I'm still so confused but thank you for the information.

Comment: @DarkEve do tell what you are confused about.